# Problems with MongoDB server, (anon):1137 exception connect failed

Tags: mongodb

I have recently installed MongoDB server on Ubuntu. It was working and I use id from PHP too but, I don't know why it started failing. It's the first time I use mongodb so I am a bit lost.

Actually, when trying to access via PHP or via shell to mongo:

```
root@ubuntu:~# /etc/init.d/mongodb restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mongodb restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
e.g. stop mongodb ; start mongodb. The restart(8) utility is also available.
mongodb start/running, process 7223
root@ubuntu:~#

root@ubuntu:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 1.6.3
Wed Sep  7 10:20:35 *** warning: spider monkey build without utf8 support.  consider rebuilding with utf8 support
connecting to: test
Wed Sep  7 10:20:35 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 (anon):1137
exception: connect failed
root@ubuntu:~#
```

The first time I used the spider monkey error wasn't there. And it worked. I tried reinstalling and nothing.

How I can solve that?

Thank you in advance! Any info I can add let me know, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it said, try this:

```
# start mongodb
```

Also take a look at [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) - an event-based replacement for the SysV init.